# Hereoku app continues to fail/crash with status 1 & 503 error when installing Redmine

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Heroku for the first time and am trying to launch a Rails 3.2.13 app, using Ruby 2.0.0 on a Cedar stack using PostgreSQL. My app runs fine locally, however I keep failing when pushing to Heroku. I've run this app on a dedicated server elsewhere, too, so I'm not sure why it's failing. I've also increased the log level to debug and this is still the only detail I receive.

```
Jul 16 15:39:48 xxx app/web.1:  => Booting WEBrick 
Jul 16 15:39:48 xxx app/web.1:  => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:52808 
Jul 16 15:39:48 xxx app/web.1:  => Call with -d to detach 
Jul 16 15:39:48 xxx app/web.1:  => Ctrl-C to shutdown server 
Jul 16 15:39:48 xxx app/web.1:  Exiting 
Jul 16 15:39:49 xxx Heroku/web.1:  State changed from starting to crashed 
Jul 16 15:39:50 xxx heroku/web.1:  Process exited with status 1 
Jul 16 15:39:58 xxx heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=xxx.herokuapp.com fwd="" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
Jul 16 15:39:58 xxx heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=xxx.herokuapp.com fwd="" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
Jul 16 15:40:06 xxx heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=xxx.herokuapp.com fwd="" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The problems were related to an obfuscated error with a Rails 2 vs Rails 3.2 plugins directory issue. Evidently Heroku places files in the vendor/plugins directory even when nothing is there.

I had to comment out my "exit 1" line in the Redmine environment.rb file.

More info and credit here: [redmine deploy on heroku cedar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444170/redmine-deploy-on-heroku-cedar)